# Can not deploy Ruby on Rails app which was deployable till Dec 2023

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, capistrano

I have a Ruby application that has been used for years and since December 2023 I can no longer deploy it. I use capistrano for deploy. Ruby should be version 2.6.1. When deploying, it gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
    The last version of bundler (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.4.22. Try installing it with `gem install bundler -v 2.4.22`
    bundler requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.1.33.
```

Installing Ruby 3.0 is not an option.
How can I manage this situation?

Comment: Did you try to install bundler according to the instructions in the error message?

Comment: This bundler use Ruby 3 and that is not an option.

Comment: But bundler 2.4.22 require Ruby 3.0.0 and my app dont work with them.

Comment: And this works perfectly with this configuration till December 2023.
I am not change anything.

Comment: @CrniMrki _"But bundler 2.4.22 require Ruby 3.0.0"_ – that's Bundler 2.5, Bundler 2.4 requires Ruby 2.6 or above.

Comment: If it used to work and suddenly stopped it means that something has changed - it wasn't necessarily your change though! The main question here is - what's your deployment process? If you, for example, use docker, your docker image maintainer might have move the tag you're using to a newer version (it does not affect only :latest tag). In short - we need to know a bit more about your deployment to help (especially around ruby and bundler versions)

Comment: Having a second look - bundler 2.4.22 has been released Nov 23 and the next version, 2.5.0 (supporting ruby 3+ only) was released on 15 of December 2023. I guess this is when your deployment stopped working. This would mean that your deployment process is set to install the latest bundler version - simply change this to install 2.4.22 amd deployment should work again (how to change this depends on your deployment script/process)

Comment: At some point you will be forced to upgrade to Ruby 3.0.0, and beyond. Whoever is telling you that this is not an option is going to make maintenance of this app more and more difficult. You will end up with obsolete/end-of-life versions of ruby and rails. If it were me, I would push back and insist that upgrading to Ruby 3.0.0 is necessary. This is my conclusion from working with Ruby/Rails since version 1.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your Gemfile.lock will tell you which version of bundler was used to create it, e.g.:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.22
```

If that is incompatible with your expected Ruby version, try removing your Gemfile.lock file and recreating it by running `bundle install` locally prior to deploying with Capistrano.

Comment: That is exactly what is strange and confusing,
In Gemfile.lock stay 
BUNDLED WITH
      1.17.3